# Excel Data Validation - Remove Header

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu

I've got a Data Validation in one worksheet, where its source is a full column in another worksheet in the same workbook, which gets it's info from an Access Database.

The table from Access has headers of course, so when I do the drop down list, it gives me the value in the header row as my first choice. Is there a way to use the whole column, but remove the header? The length of the used column will vary, otherwise, I'd just select a fixed range.

Comment: If you're using Excel365 then use `FILTER` (and or `DROP` if you have it)

Comment: `DROP()` is better ==> `DROP(array,1)` as @chrisneilsen sir said. Also with `TAKE()` ==> `=TAKE(array,-ROWS(array)+1)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks, I successfully used the DROP method to work it out. Didn't know that one existed. You rock.

Answer (score -1):

Select the range from the second cell and below with as much spare cell as required even till down. Excel will show the values only.

Somebody minused. ?

Sample:

[image: Screenshot]

So the solution works. The requirement to select the hole column is due to XY problem and should not be considered.

Comment: It wasn't me (the person who posted it), but I'm guessing because it was more of a band-aid than a fix. But appreciate the thought and assistance. I did end up using the "=DROP(array,1)" method suggested above, and it worked perfectly. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34